# how to priint string in a href = '#' or located in python

Tags: python, web-crawler

[image]

I want to get `The following term was not found in PubMed: SNP5265` this message from

```
<em class="altered-search-explanation query-error-message">The following term was not found in PubMed: SNP5265</em>
```

like picture.Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What web crawler are you using?

Comment: You should also really show that you have put some effort into finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Beautiful soup to parse the page. This answer assumes multiple instances. First install requests and Beautiful Soup with `pip install BeautifulSoup4 requests`

then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

url = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=SNP653+fever'

soup = BS(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
#find all <em> elements in soup object matching {attribute:value} condition

for x in soup.findAll('em', {"class":"altered-search-explanation query-error-message"}):
            if not(x.text ==""): # if text is not empty
                print(x.text) # or return text.. list.append(x.text)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer, in my case , I confusd about what is hearder?

Comment: ```url = https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=SNP653+fever```  this is my url. I can't find ele by ID or class or tags. I can't located what I want.

Comment: The element returns the message "The following term was not found in PubMed: SNP653". I made a couple of minor edits to the code because I copy/pasted from another project of mine. It works but it looks like the result your searching for doesn't exist in PubMed

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct - it provides you with what is needed. I suggest you refine your search queries and ensure you're looking for the right item.